# In VSCode, prevent PyLance warning: Invalid character in identifier

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, suppress-warnings, pylance

After an update to VSCode's Python plugin, PyLance is causing trouble.

```
        def (f, *args):
            if f:
                f(*args)
```

... causes "Invalid character in identifier"

[image]

How to disable these warnings?

Maybe I need to create `./.vscode/settings.json` with:

```
{
    "python.analysis.disabled": [
        "I want something like:", "invalid-character-in-identifier" ],
}
```

... but can't find anything suitable on https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference#_python-language-server-settings

Can I extrapolate the token I need somehow from VSCode?

PS Please do not critique the use of unicode variable names. That's not at point here. The variable name is valid, and the runs from the commandline.

Comment: You can try doing something like this, ```: Any```, this will make `Pylance` to recognise the the unicode variable which won't throw the squiggles anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug: https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/1286

Expect a fix in the next VSCode version.

EDIT: It's been fixed!